# Can $\sum_n \frac{1}{x_{n_{ik}}}$ still diverge if $\sum_n \frac{1}{x_{n_{i}}}$ diverge and $x_n$ is nondecreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of positive real numbers and suppose that there exists a sequence $(n_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_{n_i}} = +\infty.$$
Can I conclude that, for all $k$ big, the series $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x_{n_{ki}}}$$ diverges as well or there are counterexamples?

It seems counter-intuitive to me that we still have $\sum_{i=1}^\infty  1/{x_{n_{ki}}}$ even if $k$ is big, but I couldn't find a counterexample so I guess it can be somehow proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it diverges as well: here's a proof. Lets write $y_i = x_{n_i}$ because there are too many subscripts and the first subsequence $n_i$ is not important at all.

Since $y_i$ is non-decreasing, for the $k$ indices $j=ki+1,\dots,k(i+1)$, we have
$$ y_{ki} \le y_j \iff \frac1{y_j} \le \frac1{y_{ki}}$$
which means that, since $k$ is fixed,
$$\sum_{j=ki+1}^{k(i+1)} \frac1{y_j} \le \frac{k}{y_{ki}} $$
Taking a sum from $i=1$ to $N$,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac k{y_{ki}} \ge \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=ki+1}^{k(i+1)} \frac1{y_j} = \sum_{\iota=k+1}^{k(N+1)}\frac1{y_\iota} \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \infty .$$

Therefore $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{y_{ki}}=\infty$ as well.

If instead of $i$, you put a function of $i$ (e.g. $i^2$) then something else could happen.

Comment: If I am not wrong your first equivalence is not true...

Comment: @Filburt yeah you're not wrong. but its easy to fix, gimme a moment, sorry

Comment: I kinda see how to fix it, but take you time and thanks for the help! :-D

Comment: @Filburt fixed :) Yeah it was just a matter of which side of $y_{ki} \le y_j \le y_{k(i+1)}$ to use...

Comment: Thank you! Just one last thing. I don't see how something else could happen if instead of $k$ we had $k^2$, since in these two cases it is nothing but a constant. If the square was over $i$ however (like $x_{n_{i^2}}$) I agree that the answer wouldn't be the same!

Comment: .......@Filburt thats exactly what I meant to say, yes :) :) :) Thank you for the careful reading

Answer (score 0):

An obvious answer is if $x_n$'s are bounded above (non-decreasing, or even increasing does not guarantee unboundedness), say $x_n\leq \beta$, then for any infinite subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{n\in S} \frac{1}{x_n} \to\infty$.

Now if we assume that $x_n$'s are unbounded, taking $x_n=n$ will give you an example for your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not looking for an example but for either a proof or a *counterexample*.